# How to change UIButton Identifier to Camera Icon?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Using the Xcode interface builder, I can change the UIBarButton image icon to a built in identifier such as a search icon or a camera icon as seen below: [image]

However, I do not see anywhere I can edit the Identifier for a regular UIButton. Is it simply not possible to do this with one click like the UIBarButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: The 'types' are the only system equivalents for a UIButton]

HOWEVER, you could programmatically do the following:

```
UIButton *cameraButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
   cameraButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];

UIBarButtonItem *camera = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:cameraButton];
[camera setAction:@selector(doSomething)];
[camera setTarget:self];
```

Create a UIButton with the camera image you want. Then use the view to create a custom UIBarButtonItem.
Unfortunately, the inverse is not as simple.

Hope this helps!